# How to disable header and left bar in modal forms

Tags: yii2, adminlte

When rendering a modal form, the form is also displaying the header,footer, menu,etc of the main pages. Where or how do I go about having a modal form not render these theme features? I am using the Admin LTE theme.

Comment: You probably should use `renderPartial()` instead of `render()`.

Comment: how are you loading the modal view?

Comment: I am using the bootstrap modal, with Java script called on the button click.

Comment: i understand that but the url that you are using to load the content into the modal window is it an `action` inside a `controller`? please add your code how you are using the `Modal` either you are using the `Modal::begin()` and `Modal::end()` with your form content enclosed inside or you are loading via javascript using `.load()`